# Flutter ~ Abstract constructor workaround for Json Serialization

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization

**Background:** I would like to create an abstract `JsonSerializable` class that allows its extenders to have an `toJsonString`-method and a `fromJsonString` constructor, so that I can bundle all calls to `jsonDecode` and `jsonEncode` in that one class, while also enforcing that the extenders implement the required `toJson`-metrhod and `fromJson`-constructor.

Thus far, I have managed to do half of that like this:

`json_serializable.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

abstract class JsonSerializable {

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
  String toJsonString() => jsonEncode(toJson());
}
```

`readable_uuid.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import 'json_serializable.dart';

class ReadableUuid extends JsonSerializable {
  static const Uuid uuidGenerator = Uuid();
  String uuid = uuidGenerator.v4();

  static const String _uuidFieldName = "uuid";

  ReadableUuid();

  ReadableUuid.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : uuid = json[_uuidFieldName];

  ReadableUuid.fromJsonString(String jsonString)
      : this.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        _uuidFieldName: uuid,
      };
  [...]
}
```

`character_id.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:ceal_chronicler_f/utils/readable_uuid.dart';

import '../utils/json_serializable.dart';

class CharacterId extends JsonSerializable {
  static const String _idFieldName = "id";

  var id = ReadableUuid();

  CharacterId();

  CharacterId.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = ReadableUuid.fromJson(json[_idFieldName]);

  CharacterId.fromJsonString(String jsonString)
      : this.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    _idFieldName: id,
  };
  [...]
}
```

This is already not bad, but there's still some duplication here. Both my concrete classes still need to have a `fromJsonString` constructor that is effectively identical, and they both still need to import `dart:convert` because of that. Also, I can't enforce that they have a `fromJson` constructor like that.

Now, what I would *like* to have is something like this:

`json_serializable.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

abstract class JsonSerializable {

  abstract JsonSerializable.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
  JsonSerializable.fromJsonString(String jsonString)
      : this.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
  String toJsonString() => jsonEncode(toJson());
}
```

`readable_uuid.dart`

```dart
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import 'json_serializable.dart';

class ReadableUuid extends JsonSerializable {
  static const Uuid uuidGenerator = Uuid();
  String uuid = uuidGenerator.v4();

  static const String _uuidFieldName = "uuid";

  ReadableUuid();

  @override
  ReadableUuid.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : uuid = json[_uuidFieldName];

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        _uuidFieldName: uuid,
      };
  [...]
}
```

`character_id.dart`

```dart
import 'package:ceal_chronicler_f/utils/readable_uuid.dart';

import '../utils/json_serializable.dart';

class CharacterId extends JsonSerializable {
  static const String _idFieldName = "id";

  var id = ReadableUuid();

  CharacterId();

  @override
  CharacterId.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = ReadableUuid.fromJson(json[_idFieldName]);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    _idFieldName: id,
  };
  [...]
}
```

Now, I know this does not work because constructors are not part of the interface in Dart (and it's made more complicated by Flutter disallowing Runtime Reflection in favor of Tree Shaking). My question is, can anyone think of a workaround here that achieves as many of the following goals as possible:

- No duplicate code in concrete classes
- All dependencies on `dart:convert` are concentrated inside `JsonSerializable`
- The `fromJson` constructor and `toJson` method are enforced to exist in concrete classes

Answer (score 0):

I have now come up with a "solution" that addresses about 1.75 of the above requirements, but has some drawbacks.

First, here's the "solution":

`json_serializable.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

abstract class JsonSerializable {

  JsonSerializable();

  JsonSerializable.fromJsonString(String jsonString)
      : this.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonString));

  JsonSerializable.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap){
    decodeJson(jsonMap);
  }

  decodeJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

  String toJsonString() => jsonEncode(toJson());
}
```

`readable_uuid.dart`

```dart
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import 'json_serializable.dart';

class ReadableUuid extends JsonSerializable {
  static const Uuid uuidGenerator = Uuid();
  String uuid = uuidGenerator.v4();

  static const String _uuidFieldName = "uuid";

  ReadableUuid();

  ReadableUuid.fromJsonString(String jsonString)
      : super.fromJsonString(jsonString);

  ReadableUuid.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) : super.fromJson(jsonMap);

  @override
  decodeJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    uuid = jsonMap[_uuidFieldName];
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        _uuidFieldName: uuid,
      };
  [...]
}
```

`character_id.dart`

```dart
import 'package:ceal_chronicler_f/utils/readable_uuid.dart';

import '../utils/json_serializable.dart';

class CharacterId extends JsonSerializable {
  static const String _idFieldName = "id";

  var id = ReadableUuid();

  CharacterId();

  CharacterId.fromJsonString(String jsonString)
      : super.fromJsonString(jsonString);

  CharacterId.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) : super.fromJson(jsonMap);

  @override
  decodeJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    id = ReadableUuid.fromJson(jsonMap[_idFieldName]);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        _idFieldName: id,
      };
  [...]
}
```

**Pros**

- All dependencies on dart:convert are concentrated inside JsonSerializable
- JsonSerializable enforces the creation of `toJson` amd `decodeJson` methods
- Little boilerplate code

**Cons**

- Only works if all fields of concrete classes are either initialized with default values, late or nullable
- The conveyor-belt constructors need to be implemented every time even though they always look the same, which feels like a bit of duplication

That would be the best solution that I can come up at the moment. If anyone has a better solution, please feel free to share it here.